# Add Jest coverage threshold to create-react-app project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, package.json, create-react-app

This is the `"scripts"` section of the `package.json` file that was initially generated using `create-react-app`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "concurrently \"react-scripts start\" \"node server.js\"",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --coverage --watchAll",
  "start:server": "node server"
},
```

I would like to configure Jest to have a [coverage threshold](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#coveragethreshold-object) like this:

```
"jest": {
  "coverageThreshold": {
    "global": {
      "branches": 100,
      "functions": 100,
      "lines": 100,
      "statements": 100
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I run `yarn test` it does not look like the `"jest"` portion is being executed. Is there something extra I need to add b/c this project was built with `create-react-app`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `create-react-app` uses its own settings [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js). The easiest thing would be to eject: [`npm run eject`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/cli.html#config-path), to have the full controll over the settings.

Another way would be to copy over all the settings to your own settings and start the test with the additional parameter [`--config=<pathToYourSettings>`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/cli.html#config-path)

Answer (score 9):

### `package.json`

1. Add a new `npm script` to coverage

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "coverage": "npm test -- --coverage",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

2. And add a `jest config`

```
"jest": {
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "statements": 100,
        "branches": 50,
        "functions": 100,
        "lines": 100
      }
    }
  },
```

3. `npm run coverage`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Now, [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) could be a new path to take.

You can config Jest in `package.json` in a jest section mentioned here:
https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#2-jest-configuration---testing

Answer (score 2):

You *can* override certain coverage reporting metrics as indicated by [create-react-app#coverage-reporting](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#coverage-reporting). Mind you, this has to be configured inside your `package.json` because that is where create-react-app looks for you overrides (aka, not inside `.jestrc` or `jest.config.js` files). But as @Andreas mentioned, if you want full control, eject or create your own config.

As a side notes, you may be able to pull out the jest configuration from create-react-app by using the `--config` flag with `test` script (from jest) and just copy that into your own config with your updates. May be easier than figuring out what create-react-app is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this latest link: [Configuring threshold limit](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/)

By adding this to your package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 75,
        "functions": 75,
        "lines": 75,
        "statements": 75
      }
    }
  }
```